# How do I validate an XML file in C#, I have an Instance of XMLDocument in my Code, I don't want to use XMLReader though?

Tags: validation, object, xsd, xmldocument

I already have an XMLDocument object in my code and I want to validate that object. I have the XSD file with me. I found a way of validating it using the xmlreader but I am not using the Xml Reader anywhere in my code. I have an XMLDocument instance ready.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the schemas property on your XmlDocument object to add the xsd like so.

```
xmlDoc.Schemas.Add(namespace, xsdFileName);
```

then you can load your xml file and then call the Validate method passing it a ValidationEventHandler like so.

```
xmlDoc.Load(xmlfileName);
xmlDoc.Validate(handler);
```

Comment: I tried the xmlDoc.Schemas.Add(namespace, xsdFileName);
but for some reason the schema was not getting attached.

Answer (score 0):

XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Schemas.Add("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema", "fileName.xsd");
ValidationEventHandler validationEventHandler = new System.Xml.Schema.ValidationEventHandler(ValidationEVentHandler);
xmlDoc.Load("fileName.xml");
xmlDoc.Validate(validationEventHandler);

public void ValidationEventHandler(object sender, ValidationEventArgs e)
        {
            switch (e.Severity)
            {
                case XmlSeverityType.Error:
                    lblLabel.Text= e.Message;
                    break;
                case XmlSeverityType.Warning:
                    lblLabel.Text = e.Message;
                    break;
             }
        }

Comment: I generated xsd from an online converter tool for my XML

Comment: Got the Solution. Actually, it was the xmlns problem in my XSD and XML. Thanks!